# Howto bind a click event in a Backbone subview

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I'm having problems understanding the event binding in a Backbone subview. My view is defined as follows:

```
TenantView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click": "setActive"
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.parentEl = this.options.parentEl;
    return this.render();
  },
  template: new EJS({
    url: '/scripts/templates/tenant.ejs'
  }),
  render: function() {
    $(this.parentEl).children('ul').append(this.template.render(this.model));
    return this;
  },
  setActive: function(event) {
    return this.model.set('active', true);
  }
});
```

The template simply consists of an `li` containg an `a`. Done this way, clicks events on my view are not catched, my method `setActive` is never triggered.

When I extend my view by an `el` property like `el: 'li'` one of my (2) views acts properly and triggers the `setActive` function. The second view does not react at all. If I insepct the `el` property during the views initialization, the working view's `el` property points to the right `li`, the failing views `el` points to the first `li` that can be found in the page.

As one can see, I am totally lost when it comes to the meaning of the `el` property.

Question is, how can I bind a click on view to this very views `setActive` function?

Can anyone enlighten me please?

Regards
Felix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, you may read [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624929/backbone-view-el-confusion). Explanation about `el` is given there.

As `TenantView` has `parentEl` property, I'm assuming it is being rendered from some `parent_view`. I would suggest some approach like below and give it a try.

```
var ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName : "li", // change it according to your needs

  events : {
    "click": "setActive"
  },

  initialize : function() {
    _.bindAll(this, "setActive");
    // code to initialize child_view
  },

  render : function() {
    // as I'm not familiar with the way you are using template, 
    // I've put simple call to render template, but it should render the
    // content to be kept inside "li" tag
    this.$el.html(this.template()); 

    return this;
  },

  setActive : function(event) {
    // code to be executed in event callback
  }
});


var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el : "#parent_view_el",

  initialize : function() {
    // parent view initialization code
  },

  render : function() {
    // a place from where ChildView is initialized
    // might be a loop through collection to initialize more than one child views
    // passing individual model to the view

    var child_view = new ChildView();

    this.$("ul").append(child_view.render().$el); // equivalent to this.$el.find("ul")

    return this;
  }
});
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Cyclone, thank you for your answer. In fact that's nearly what I am doing. The parentEl property points to the CollectionViews el property(which is a ul), so that I can render my ChildViews inside the ul. In my parent CollectionView I iterate over the collections models and create a ChildView instance for each. I have the feeling, that approach is totally wrong.

Comment: Hmmm, thats what I've been following, works pretty well for me :)

Comment: Reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624929/backbone-view-el-confusion) actually solved my problem. See my comment below. Thanks again for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You have kind of disabled backbones natural behavior by introducing your `parentEl` property and circumventing the creation of a view element. You basically never wire up the views `elz property to anything.

If I get your code right, the `TenantView` is a single list item in a list of tenants.

In your `TenantView` you can do this to leverage backbones built in events:

```
render: function() {
    this.setElement(this.template.render(this.model));
    $(this.parentEl).children('ul').append(this.$el);
    return this;
}
```

The `setElement` function will use the return value of you `template` function to wire up the views element and also setup the events for you. In the documentation it is suggested to use `setElement` in favor of just assigning something to the `el` property. There is also the nifty `$el` property which will contain a cached jQuery (or Zepto) object of your view's element.

To go more in the *backbone way* personally I would consider something like this:

```
var TenantView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // =========
    // = Setup =
    // =========

    events: {
        "click": "setActive"
    },

    template: new EJS({
        url: '/scripts/templates/tenant.ejs'
    }),

    // =============
    // = Lifecycle =
    // =============

    initialize: function(model, options) {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        var content = this.template.render(this.model);
        this.$el.html(content);
        return this;
    },

    // ==========
    // = Events =
    // ==========

    setActive: function(event) {
        return this.model.set('active', true);
    }

});


var TenantList = Backbone.View.extend({

    // =========
    // = Setup =
    // =========

    id: "tenantList",
    tagName: "ul",

    // =============
    // = Lifecycle =
    // =============

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        if (this.collection.length > 0) {
            this.renderChildren();
        }
    },

    renderChildren: function() {
        var that = this;

        this.collection.each(function(tenant) {
            that.$el.append(new TenantView(tenant).$el);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Torsten, thanks for your reply. setElement seems to properly set the el property of my views during rendering now. Unfortunately the click events are not catched either way. I think my whole approach of rendering ChildViews inside a CollectionView is totally wrong.

Comment: Well in a kind of way... Backbone kind of expects you to have an element after initialization and only fill this with the render function. In theory the `setElement` function should take care of events. Which version of backbone do you use?

Comment: I'm using 0.9.2. What solved the problem so far was setting `tagname` to 'li' for the ChildView. Then remove the li from the template. I changed the render method of my ChildView to: this.el.innerHTML = this.template.render(this.model) and changed the render method of my CollectionView to: $(this.el).children('ul').append(viewInstance.render().el) where viewInstance's are iterated over. I'm still unsure whether this approach is the right one.