# Why the backbone view.el is 'body' everything is ok but be broken when view.el is '#container'?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am a newer for backbone. There is [a link for my code.](http://jsfiddle.net/uhLmp36h/)

```
$(function (){
  var test = {};
    test.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'body',
        initialize: function (){
            this.input = $('#new-todo');
        },
        events: {
            'keyup #new-todo': 'check'
        },
        check: function (){
      console.log('!');
            $('#test').html(this.input.val());
        }
    });
    test.view = new test.View();
});
```

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624929/backbone-view-el-confusion) but still confused it.When I set `el:'#container'` the `keyup` event doesn't work.

I want to know, what is it the `View.el`, what's is that its function? What's the different from `el: 'body'` and `el: '#container'`.

Comment: Can you add the html where the container is defined?

Comment: @GiuseppePes the first div's id is `#container`

Comment: with `#` in the name?

Comment: @ToddMark: did my answer help? Did it clear your doubt?

Comment: @A.J maybe more clear cut, I need do a demo to understand a later and confirm your answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone expects the view to only handle the events within it's specific DOM element(**el**). Your `#new-todo` is outside `#container`

> I want to know, what is it the View.el, what's is that its function? What's the different from el: 'body' and el: '#container'.

el is the element the view refers to all the time. The events are attached to elements within this el element.

Think for it this way: The view only refers to el element.

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#View I read the document again and think over your answer **only handle the events within it's specific DOM**. I understand the `view.el`. It's a range like a scope of function. All the elements events could be fired by the `view.el`. Thanks for your help :)